# Java or Coldfusion File operation

Tags: java, coldfusion

I am using Coldfusion MX and I want to create parts of .htaccess file dynamically.

for example I have a Start And End of a part looks like

```
> # --- Start Part1 ---#
> 
> # --- End Part1 ---#
```

now every time I generate this .htaccess contents in coldfusion I want to delete the contents between `Start and End`
parts and write the new contents here.

Is it possible in Coldfusion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume a file `.htaccess.template` as such:

```
# BEFORE
# --- Start Part1 ---#

# --- End Part1 ---#
# AFTER
```

In the same directory there's a ColdFusion script, say `htaccess.cfm` (name doesn't matter):

```
<!--- note double pound signs, necessary to escape in CF --->
<cfset start = "## --- Start Part1 ---##">
<cfset end = "## --- End Part1 ---##">

<cfsavecontent variable="replacement"><cfoutput>
I will appear between the start and end comments!
Replace me with what you want to appear in the .htaccess file.
</cfoutput></cfsavecontent>

<cfset template = fileRead(getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()) & "/.htaccess.template")>

<cfset startPos = find(start, template)>
<cfset endPos = find(end, template)>

<cfset before = left(template, startPos + len(start) - 1)>
<cfset after = right(template, len(template) - endPos + 1)>

<cfset content = "#before##replacement##after#">

<!--- <cfoutput><pre>#content#</pre></cfoutput> --->

<cfset path = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()) & "/.htaccess">
<cfif fileExists(path)><cfset fileDelete(path)></cfif>
<cfset fileWrite(path, content)>
```

This will generate a file `.htaccess` in the same directory. I think the one issue will be dealing with any file system locks placed on `.htaccess`, preventing deletion / overwriting, where I'm unsure what you'd need to do in that situation.

In this example .htaccess will be:

```
# BEFORE
# --- Start Part1 ---#
I will appear between the start and end comments!
Replace me with what you want to appear in the .htaccess file.
# --- End Part1 ---#
# AFTER
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the file into a var with `<cffile>`
2. turn the var into an array using `listToArray()`, using endline chr's as delimiter
3. open a `<cfsavecontent>` block
4. loop through and output the array until you reach `# --- Start Part1 ---#`
5. add your own content
6. loop through and skip the array until you reach `# --- End Part1 ---#`
7. loop through and output the array until you reach the end
8. write the saved content to a new .htaccess with `<cffile>`

Unfortunately, not until CF8 that we can use read an arbitrarily large file line-by-line without exhausting memory.  See: http://coldfused.blogspot.com/2007/07/new-file-io-in-coldfusion-8.html